# jqxGrid + Bootstrap 3.2.0 modal – unable to select input 'text' box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jqxgrid, jqwidget

I am using **Bootstrap 3.2.0 Modal** for displaying the **jqxGrid** with filtering functionality. All functionality of jqxGrid filtering (Sorting, Select Box) is working, except for typing text in the filtering input box. I am not able to find a solution on this issue. Please help.

I am not able to type in the `input` boxes given below. It is not focusing, but I am able to inspect element using dev tools.

[image: Modal]

Not even the value is getting placed, when edited with dev tools.

[image: Peculiar]

**CODE**: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yprLbyu7/3/show/ or http://jsfiddle.net/yprLbyu7/3/

Comment: can you show us  your necessary code here ,and do u getting any error?

Comment: @kki3908050 I have updated the code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
**working fine here**   
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title id='Description'>The sample illustrates the basic functionality of the jqxInput widget. The jqxInput widget provides suggestions while you type into the field. The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the "source" property. </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/scripts/demos.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/jqwidgets/jqxinput.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body class='default'>
        <div id='content'>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {              
                    var countries = new Array("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burma", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Democratic Republic", "Congo, Republic of the", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "East Timor", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, North", "Korea, South", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Mongolia", "Morocco", "Monaco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Qatar", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino", " Sao Tome", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia and Montenegro", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe");
                    $("#input").jqxInput({placeHolder: "Enter a Country", height: 25, width: 200, minLength: 1,  source: countries });
                });
            </script>
           <input type="text" id="input"/>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please check the question. I am asking about jqxGrid filtering, not  jqxInput.